# Endpoint inequality for Poisson integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-equations

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth and compactly supported function. We know that the function
$$
w(x) := - \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(y) \log|x-y| \ dy
$$
is the only solution to the problem
$$
-\Delta w = f, \text{ on } \mathbb{R}^2
$$
with the property that its gradient vanishes at infinity.

From Calderon--Zygmund theory, for a given $1 < p < \infty$, it follows that the inequality holds true:
$$
\|\partial_i \partial_j w\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)} \leq C_p \|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)}.
$$
Indeed, $\partial_i \partial_j u = R_{ij} u = \partial_i \partial_j (- \Delta^{-1})u$, the Riesz transform, which is a Calderon--Zygmund operator.

Usually textbooks prove the fact that Calderon-Zygmund operators send $L^\infty$ into $BMO$. But I would like something different. Namely, my question is: **does the following inequality (*) hold true?**

$$
\|\partial_i \partial_j w\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)} \leq C \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)} (1 + \log( e+\|\partial^2 w\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)})) \qquad (*)
$$
Here, we denoted $\|\partial^2 w\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)} := \sum_{i =1,2, \, j = 1,2}\|\partial_i \partial_j w\|$.
This inequality loses a logarithm, and I have no clue in how to start proving it. I tried writing down the expression for $w$ in terms of principal value, and integrating by parts near the singularity, but it does not help. One could think of splitting the principal value integral in two parts, one in a ball near the singularity, say of size $\delta$, and then optimize in terms of $\delta$. But again, no clue in how to deal with the part near the singularity.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd say it is false. The inequality implies $||\partial^2 w||_{\infty}\le C||f||_{\infty}(1+\log(e+||\partial^2 w||_{\infty}))$, but there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ such that $||f_n||_{\infty}=1$ and $||\partial^2 w||_{\infty}\to \infty$, which contradicts $||\partial^2 w||_{\infty}\le C(1+\log(e+||\partial^2 w||_{\infty}))$. Not sure about the comment. If I wanted to prove that the inequality holds, I'd use the $L^{\infty}\to BMO$ boundedness and John-Nirenberg inequality.

Comment: @user90189 Thanks for the hint! Could you please describe the sequence you are mentioning?

Comment: Use $f=\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}$.

Comment: @user90189, I guess I can construct a sequence out of the function you mention just by multiplying by a cut-off function, and letting the cut-off radius go to infinity. Now I have a further question. Is it possible to find such a sequence $f_k$ with uniformly bounded $L^2$ norm? Because it seems to me that what is causing trouble in your example are the ``tails at infinity''. Also, for the application I am thinking of, $L^2$ boundedness of $f$ is already granted (as other things, but let's start from this one).

Comment: Dear @snefs, the problem is the origin, not so much the tail at infinity. I could equally write $f=\frac{x_1x_2}{|x|^2}\chi_{B(0,1)}$, which belongs to every $L^p$. You may notice that $\partial_1\partial_2w(0)=\infty$, so I thought about  $f_n=\frac{x_1x_2}{|x|^2}\chi_{B(0,1)\setminus B(0,1/n)}$. The function $\partial_1\partial_2w$ blows up rather slowly, logarithmically, at 0, so it is "almost" bounded.

Comment: In fact, it is easier to say that $\partial_i\partial_j w\notin L^{\infty}$ for $f$ I wrote, so your inequality is meaningless :)